# call libyahoo2 functions from C#

Tags: c#, c++, c

I am writing an IM application in C#. I am wondering what is the best library that I can use to implement yahoo messaging function in my app. I come across libyahoo2 http://libyahoo2.sourceforge.net/ and pigdin library http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/WhatIsLibpurple but they are all written in C/C++ so I dont know which one is better to use and how can I call functions in those lib from C#. Can I use PInvoke or should I write wrapper ?

I also tried to port the JAVA YAHOO API to C# using Java Language Conversion Assistant but I don't think it will work since it seems that some JAVA part does not have equivalent .NET.
Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If all the methods you want are static, you can just P/Invoke everything you need

Answer (score 0):

If you know C++ and the library will build in Visual Studio, the easiest thing to do is create a C++/CLI project out of the source and then use it to add managed classes to the project.

In C++/CLI, you can automatically marshall simple types from C to .NET and the managed classes you create can be called easily in C#.  The result of the build is an assembly.